# Solution methods for system of ODE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I'm reading Coddington's "Introudction to ordinary differential equations". In chapter 6, the author discusses systems of differential equations. One of the exercises is to find the solution $\hat{\phi}$ the system $$y_1'=y_1,$$ $$y_2'=y_1 + y_2,$$

which satisfies $\hat{\phi}(0)=(1,2).$ Yet, there is no discussion about a systematic way to solve these kinds of systems. I know how to solve it by first writing the system in matrix form $$\hat{y}=\bigg(\begin{matrix}  1&0 \\1 &1 \end{matrix}\bigg)\ \bigg(\begin{matrix} y_1 \\y_2 \end{matrix}\bigg)$$

and then finding the general solutions with the eigenvalues/vectors of this matrix. This method is not mentioned in the book, so I think there might be other ways to solve this system. So are the other solution methods? I think its useful to have other tools besides the eigenvalue/vector type, since it is quite tedious to apply that to large systems.

Comment: You can first solve the first for $y_1$ separately. Inserting the solution into the second equation gives a scalar equation for $y_2$. No matrix methods needed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y'_1-y_1=0$$
$$ (y_1e^{-t})'=0$$
Integrate:
$$ y_1e^{-t}=C_1$$
$$\implies y_1=e^{t}C_1$$
Then solve the second DE:
$$y'_2-y_2=y_1$$
$$(y_2e^{-t})'=y_1e^{-t}$$
$$(y_2e^{-t})'=C_1$$
Integrate:
$$ y_2e^{-t}=C_1t+C_2$$
$$\implies y_2=e^{t}(C_1t+C_2)$$